# dimension of analytic variety?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, analytic-geometry

Let $g_1,..., g_t$ be real analytic functions defined on an open subset $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.
Then
$$
X = \{ x: g_1(x) = ... = g_t(x) = 0 \}
$$
is called an analytic variety. In algebraic geometry, if all the $g$s where polynomials we expect the dimension to be $n - t$. Do we expect the same behaviour for analytic varieties?

Also what is a $0$ dimensional analytic variety? Is is a countable set? (in comparison to finite points in algebraic geometry?) Any comments are appreciated! Also I am looking for a reference for this. Thank you

Comment: Please include context, when you ask questions.  As a member of this site for six years, I'm surprised I find you in need of being reminded of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement about the expected dimension in algebraic geometry is problematic (really, you should say "for sufficiently nice collections of $g_i$," at least). Things get even worse once we move to analytic spaces: the function $\sum_{i=0}^r x_i^2$ cuts out an analytic space of dimension $n-r$ inside $\Bbb R^n$, so you really don't have much that's positive to say here about this question. In fact, any analytic variety can be written as the zero locus of a single equation: if we look at the variety cut out by $g_1=0,\cdots,g_r=0$, then the same variety is cut out by $\sum g_i^2$.

For the second question, if you work inside a copy of $\Bbb R^n$, then it is true that a zero-dimensional analytic variety must be at most countable. Any uncountable set in $\Bbb R^n$ has an accumulation point, so an analytic function vanishing on such a set is identically zero.

---

Before giving you a reference for more material on such things, let me make a brief discussion on the history of the field so you have some context. Frequently the objects you mention are also called real-analytic spaces ("variety" tends to come with a smoothness or reducedness assumption). They have not enjoyed the same popularity as some other closely connected fields - they were an active part of geometry in the 1950s and 60s (Hironaka proves resolution of singularities for analytic spaces as well as algebraic varieties, for instance) with Grauert, Remmert, Cartan, etc providing many contributions, but as Grothendieck-style algebraic geometry grew, they faded a bit from prominence. Adding to this the fact that real-analytic spaces were never as popular in the literature as complex-analytic spaces and there's a little bit of a dearth of writing out there about them.

From a perspective emphasizing the sheaf-related issues, one text I've found useful is Guaraldo, Macri, and Tancredi's [*Topics on Real Analytic Spaces*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-322-84243-5) (1986). One can also analyze such spaces via semi-analytic geometry and more generally o-minimal geometry, though one has to pay attention to the fact that analytic varieties don't actually form an o-minimal structure and must be enlarged a bit. I'm a little more familiar with this side of things, and one jumping off point I like is Denkowska and Denkowski's survey article [*A long and winding road to definable sets*](http://dx.doi.org/10.5427/jsing.2015.13d), perhaps followed by Bierstone and Millman's [Semianalytic and subanalytic sets](http://www.numdam.org/item/PMIHES_1988__67__5_0/).

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! After I've read your answer I've been trying to decide if I should call the object (in question) analytic space or variety. In the referenced book Topics on Real Analytic Spaces in Definition 1.2 they seem to call it 'variety', or am I misunderstanding this and it would be called analytic space in this book?  Thank you

Comment: I generally lean towards referring towards everything as a real-analytic space and then adding adjectives - I find that it reduces opportunities for confusion. Do note that if you're going to follow the conventions of the linked book, the choice depends on the structure sheaf which you haven't specified in your question. Therefore deciding what structure sheaf you're going to use on $X$ is probably the first step to resolving your query.

Comment: Thank you! I don't mean to be overly picky about this detail (sorry!), but I'm still a bit confused. Defn 1.2 in Chapter II states: Let $A$ be an open subset of $k^n$ and $M$ be a subset of $A$; $M$ is a closed $k$-analytic subvariety of $A$ if for every $a \in A$ there exist an open neighbourhood $U$ of $a$ in $A$ and analytic functions $f_1,.., f_p \in \Gamma(U, O_{k^n})$ such that $$ M \cap U =  \{ x \in U  :  f_1(x) = .. = f_p(x) = 0\} .$$ Here it seems that there is no mention of sheaf on $M$ and they call it an analytic variety?

Comment: Read a few lines further until the paragraph starting with "[l]et $I_M$ be the sheaf of ideals..." which explains how to put a reduced structure sheaf on that object in a unique way - right before definition 1.6 in that section, they explain that they "mostly omit structure sheaves to indicated analytic varieties". (There are of course other options, akin to the scheme-theoretic difference between $V(x)$ and $V(x^2)$.)